# PHP Header & Footer

Tags: php, header, include, footer

I am trying to create a common header & footer for my entire website. But my webpages are organized in different folders. How should i define my links inside the PHP file so that i can include them in all the pages.Below in a part of my menu.php file.

```
Code:Root
<li>
<a href="company.html" <?php echo $active[2] ?>>COMPANY</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="team.html"><strong>Our</strong> Team</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html#clienteles"><strong>Our</strong> Clientele</a></li>
<li><a href="company.html#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="others/profile.html"><strong>Our</strong> Profile</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

Code: Child
<li>
<a href="../company.html" <?php echo $active[2] ?>>COMPANY</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="../team.html"><strong>Our</strong> Team</a></li>
<li><a href="../index.html#clienteles"><strong>Our</strong> Clientele</a></li>
<li><a href="../company.html#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="../others/profile.html"><strong>Our</strong> Profile</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I don't want to use absolute path, because i am testing the site in a local apache server on my mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should* use an absolute path. Just create a `BASE_URL` constant for your project and point it to your base URL. After that just append it to your URLS

```
<li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/team.html"><strong>Our</strong> Team</a></li>
...
...
...
<li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/path/team.html"><strong>Our</strong> Team</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would include a file, possibly config.php and inside have an absolute path. This way, even if you test your site locally, you would just need to change this one constant and use it in any link you want.

Answer (score 0):

If these pages are on the document root you can prefix them with a slash:

```
<li><a href="/team.html"><strong>Our</strong> Team</a></li>
```

As on Unix / will provide a path to the root, whether it's `http://localhost/team.html` or `http://example.com/team.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use use the [`<base>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). Once it's included, you can use relative links and browsers will look in the right place.

If you really don't want to switch the url in `<base>` back and forth for different domains, you could try setting it dynamically using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to have an object which would render the layout and whatever page you want to display at the time.

Your layout would look like this:

mylayout.phtml

```
<html>
<head><?php $title ?></head>
<body>
<div id="header"
</div>

<?php include($_GET['webpage']) ?>

<div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You will then only call the same page all the time

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?webpage=team
```

Then you create a .htaccess with mod rewrite to change your urls to

```
http://www.mysite/team/
```

It seems a bit of a stretch to just get a page displayed but by spending some time in developing a structure and a standard way to call all your pages, you will gain greater control on your template, save time in coding and have a header and footer on every page.